# How to change Microsoft Word Options Trust Center programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to change Microsoft Word Options Trust Center options programatically so I can add a new add-in catalog.

I was looking into the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library, but didn't find that option.
Is it possible to even do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. Trust center settings are stored in the windows registry. Check out the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\word\options` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\TrustedCatalogs\` hives or use the [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out windows registry changes when you apply changes in Word settings. See [Using Process Monitor to track registry changes](https://superuser.com/questions/317877/using-process-monitor-to-track-registry-changes) for more information.

Also you may consider using Group Policy Objects to roll out changes to the whole organization. See `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Microsoft <Product Name>\<Product Name> Options\Security\Trust Center\` for more information.

Comment: I tried what you said but I can't find the registry key nor the group policy.
Couldn't find office in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies.

Comment: Have you tried using the `ProcessMonitor` utility to find out the windows registry path?

Comment: Okay, just found it.  
When I add a new catalog it is stored here:  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\TrustedCatalogs\{guid id}.  
I managed to get it working via c#.  
Thanks a lot for your help.  
Now I have to learn how to create a local shared folder on Windows.